# Laravel pivot table is empty in datababase

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple form for adding pages information,  the form looks like this

[image]

as you can see above the prebid input, To add prebids we need to click plus button and pop up appear inside a popo up, I  have a form which contains the following inputs

```
1.bidder_name                   
2.params_name                   
3.params_value
```

So now when the user saves the prebids inputs from pop up , data are saved to the table named `parameters` and then the user clicks `add page` button and the data are saved to the table named `pages` ,

I would like to link up the added page with added parameters(prebids inputs).

Here is what I have tried so far

Page model

```
class Page extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =[
        "title",
        "articles",
        "status"
    ];
    public function parameter(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Parameter');
    }
}
```

Parameter model

```
 public function pages(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pages');
    }
```

Here is pivot table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('page_parameter', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('page_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('page_id')->references('id')->on('pages');
        $table->bigInteger('parameter_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('parameter_id')->references('id')->on('parameters');
    });
}
```

Here is hwo it look in phpmyadmin

[image]

Here is store function to save prebids inputs(parameters) inside parameter controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
        // dd($request);

        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $rules = array(
                'params_name.*'  => 'required',
                'params_value.*'  => 'required',
                'bidders_name.*' => 'required'
            );
            $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if($error->fails())
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'error'  => $error->errors()->all()
                ]);
            }

            $params_name = $request->params_name;
            $params_value =$request->params_value;
            $bidders_name =$request->bidders_name;

            for($count = 0; $count < count($params_name); $count++)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'params_name'   => $params_name[$count],
                    'params_value'  => $params_value[$count],
                    'bidders_name'  => $bidders_name[$count],

                );

                $insert_data[] = $data; 
                // dd($insert_data);

            }

            Parameter::insert($insert_data);
            return response()->json([
                'success'  => 'Data Added successfully.'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Now when user save data to database, I can see data saved to pages table and parameter table but the pivot table is empty.

I am so new to laravel,

Now when I save the data to the database, the `page_parameter table`(pivot table) is empty;

What am I doing wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to create page item:

```
$page=Page::create(your data);
```

after that

```
$page->parameter()->insert($insert_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Tag model  many to many relation ship

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
    }
}


// // Post model  many to many relation ship


namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Post extends Model
{
  public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
    }
}

// Show tag with post
<td>{{$tag->posts->count() }}</td>

// show post with tag 

<td>{{$post->tags->name}}</td>
```